# Video Module: YouTube controls missing for one video but not the others?

Tags: 7

Super strange issue: I've installed the Video drupal module, and it works great. However i've uploaded two separate videos, and for some reason, the YouTube controls disappear on this video:

http://truecallingcanada.com/video/seaspan-large-ship-welder

But not on this video (uploaded the same way):

http://truecallingcanada.com/video/not-for-the-faint-of-heart

Any idea as to why this module is removing controls from the former? If so, how can I fix this? I want controls on all uploads (and yes, the video embed settings are set to display controls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YT controls are there, but they're hidden behind the div.grey-bar element.

I'm seeing a difference between the two pages in this block:

```
<div class="content clearfix">
  <div class="field field-name-field-subtitle field-type-textfield-label-above">
    <div class="field-label">Subtitle:&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">Chef and Restaurant Owner</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The page showing the controls has data in this field, making the div.content block taller (essentially pushing div.grey-bar down).